# Query Parameters not working when default api prefix is changed to something else

Tags: php, laravel, api, nginx

I am using Laravel 7.0.

I have created a new module and in the new modules RouteServiceProvider.php file changed the prefix of the API routes to **cp**.

[image]

I am now trying to send some query parameters but nothing is received in the controller action method.
Here you can see the Laravel Telescope also not showing any query parameters. I checked the Nginx logs and query parameters are present there.

[image]

[image]

`php artisan route:list` is showing the route correctly.
[image]

Here is the code of the controller.

```
<?php

namespace Modules\SomeModule\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

class PartnerController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * List all Partners
     *
     * @param Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $page = $request->query('page'); // it is always null
        $pageSize = $request->query('page_size'); // it is always null

        return response()->json(['page' => $page, 'page_size' => $pageSize]);
    }
}
```

Here is the code of RouteServiceProvider. I am using nWidart/laravel-modules package to generate modules in my app.

```
<?php

namespace Modules\SomeModule\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The module namespace to assume when generating URLs to actions.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $moduleNamespace = 'Modules\SomeModule\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Called before routes are registered.
     *
     * Register any model bindings or pattern based filters.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();

    }

    /**
     * Define the "api" routes for the application.
     *
     * These routes are typically stateless.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('api')
            ->prefix('cp')
            ->namespace($this->moduleNamespace)
            ->group(module_path('SomeModule', '/Routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

When I changed the API prefix back to **api** it works absolutely fine.
Can someone please guide what is going on here? Thanks!

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? What output are you getting from `php artisan route:list`? What is your code from the relevant controller?

Comment: @maiorano84 I am using Laravel 7.0 and added the details you asked for in the question.

Answer (score 0):

So anyone who is facing the same issue when they try to remove the **api** prefix from the urls or want to replace it with something else.

In my case i have replaced **api** prefix for some of my apis with a new prefix **cp**.

Here is the answer!

In my case the problem was in Nginx configuration. Nginx was not passing the **Query Parameters** to the index.php file.

```
server {

    # server name and logs
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/mysite.com_error.log;

    root /var/www/mysite.com/public/;
    index index.html index.php;

    # location for vue app 
    location / {
        root /var/www/app.mysite.com/public/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # location for laravel api
    location /api {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # location for SomeModule  api (Adding this block fixed by issue)
    location /cp {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

**Remember to restart Nginx after updating the configuration**

```
sudo service nginx restart
```